# how to display left side in parent and subcategory in magento

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

I have display like this

```
COMPUTERS (parent category)
    ibm   <--- sub category 
    apple
    acer
    asus
MONITORS
```

Answer (score 0):

I will make a wild guess and say you need [Vertical Navigation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Rico+Neitzel/extension/763/vertical-navigation-with-css-classes).